# File not found error AWSiOSSDK AmazonServiceExceptionUnmarshaller.h

Tags: ios, aws-sdk-ios

I’ve run up an old project which uses AWSiOSSDK 1.7.1 in Cocoapods and tried to compile;

```
#import "AutoScalingAdjustmentTypeUnmarshaller.h"
#ifdef AWS_MULTI_FRAMEWORK
#import <AWSRuntime/AmazonServiceExceptionUnmarshaller.h>
#else
#import "../AmazonServiceExceptionUnmarshaller.h” <-- File not found error
#endif
```

I can remove the ../ from the beginning of the header and it finds the file but I would need to remove them all, and there is 1900 occurrences.  Also, since it's cocoapods, all the files are locked so it's not made easy.  What am I missing or how can I resolve this?

Comment: The AWS SDK for iOS v1 was deprecated last year and does not officially support CocoaPods. It also does not officially support iOS 8 and later, either. You should consider migrating to the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS v2 as soon as possible.